# Prove a special form of Schur polynomial identity

Tags: polynomials, determinants

Let $A_k$ be the  $n\times n$ matrix defined by
$$
A_k=\left[
\begin{array}{}
  1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-2} & x_1^k \\
  1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-2} & x_2^k \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{n-2} & x_n^k
\end{array}\right].
$$
If $k=n-1$, the matrix $A_{n-1}$ is called the Vandermonde matrix and the
 determinant of $A_{n-1}$ is given by
$$
\det (A_{n-1})= \prod_{1 \mathop \le i \mathop < j \mathop \le n} \left({x_j - x_i}\right).
$$

My question is how to prove 
$$
\det (A_n)= (x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n)\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \left({x_j - x_i}\right).\tag{1}
$$
 I know that $\det (A_n)$ is a kind of [Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial), but I don't know how to apply the Schur polynomial to prove Eq. $(1)$.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You want $k=n$. The formula is then just a special case of the bialternant formula for Schur functions. It is also easy to prove directly.

Comment: @RichardStanley We know that if $x_i=x_j$, for some $i\neq j$ then two row of $A_n$ is zero and hence $\prod \left({x_j - x_i}\right)$ is apart of $\det (A_{n-1})$. Moreover, one of the term of $\det (A_{n-1})$ is multiplying of elements of diagonal of $A_n$ which is $x_2x_3^2\cdots x_{n-1}^{n-2}x_{n}^n$, but the degree of $x_n$ in $\prod \left({x_j - x_i}\right)$ is $n-1$ and therefore we need $x_n$. I dont know this argument can be applied to other $x_i$;s. Also I want to ask you to make a reference for "bialternant formula for Schur functions" that you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Let $P(x) = (x - x_1) \ldots (x - x_n)$, the monic polynomial with the $x_i$ as roots.  Then $P(x)$ is of the form $x^n - (x_1 + \cdots + x_n) x^{n-1}$ plus lower-degree stuff.  So you can express $x^n$ as $(x_1 + ... + x_n) x^{n-1}$ plus stuff that will vanish in the determinant.  Done.

Comment: @RaviBoppana Thanks for your comment. I have a question.  Why [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_i$, $0\leq i \leq n-2$ are zero in $P(x)$?

Comment: The elementary symmetric polynomials are not zero.  Still the low-degree terms will not contribute to the determinant.  That's because if you have a matrix with two equal columns, then its determinant is zero.

Comment: @RaviBoppana Unfortunately, I can not understand why did you write " you can  express $x^n$ as $(x_1 + ... + x_n) x^{n-1}$ plus stuff that will vanish in the determinant." Is it possible to ask you to explain more. Maybe it be a simple fact but I do not get it. Thanks.

Comment: Ravi suggests that you rewrite each $x_i^n$ in the rightmost column of $A_n$ as $P\left(x_i\right) + \left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\right) x_i^{n-1} - \sum\limits_{u=0}^{n-2} \pm e_{n-u} x_i^u$, where the $e_v$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Once you have done this, you next notice that the $P\left(x_i\right)$ addend is $0$, so can be ignored. You're left with $\left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\right) x_i^{n-1} - \sum\limits_{u=0}^{n-2} \pm e_{n-u} x_i^u$. By the multilinearity of the determinant, you then split the determinant ...

Comment: ... of the matrix into several other determinants, which have the same first $n-1$ columns as $A_n$ but different $n$-th columns. Only one of these determinants has any chance to be nonzero, since each of the others has two equal columns. The nonzero one is a Vandermonde determinant, but it is multiplied with $x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n$. Anyway, this question is best suited for math.stackexchange.com, where it would probably have received less terse answers.

Comment: i appreciate you for your useful comments. I wish I could male a vote to your comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The argument I was thinking of is to note that $A_n$ is the Vandermonde times a symmetric function $f$ of degree one, so $f=c(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$. It is easy to see that $c=1$, e.g., by looking at the main diagonal term of the determinant. Incidentally, this result was one of two results on Schur functions (though of course not with that name) by Cauchy. The other was that $s_{1^n}(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1\cdots x_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly Exercise 6.16 in [Darij Grinberg, *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10), except that the order of columns in my exercise is the other way round (which is why I end up with $\prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \left(x_i-x_j\right)$ instead of $\prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \left(x_j-x_i\right)$). Of course, the difference is insubstantial: Reversing the order of the columns of an $n\times n$-matrix multiplies its determinant by $\left(-1\right)^{n\left(n-1\right)/2}$.

This is also (again, after the same reversal of the order of the columns) a consequence of "Corollary (The Bi-Alternant Formula)" in [John R. Stembridge, *A Concise Proof of the Littlewood-Richardson Rule*](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v9i1n5), applied to $\mu = \left(1,0,0,\ldots,0\right)$ (with $n-1$ zeroes), since what he calls $a_\rho$ is the usual Vandermonde determinant $\prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \left(x_i-x_j\right)$. This is the argument that Richard Stanley has been alluding to.

**EDIT:** The very same question has been posted, and answered by me, at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024496/computing-an-almost-vandermonde-matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer professor Grinberg. Now I am reading your interesting book.

Comment: @darijgrinberg By article you mentioned, $a_{\lambda +p}=s_{\lambda}a_p$, where $\lambda=\{0,0,0,\cdots ,0,1\}$ which result in $s_{\lambda}=e_1$ and finish. Am I right?

Comment: @user0410: Correct, except that the $p$ should be a $\rho$.